# Get position from click on Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, view, onclicklistener, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using the Google Map API for Android and what I would like to do is to add a custom view wherever the user clicks on the screen. Just like the InfoWindow but I want to have buttons inside the view. I've tried some listeners but none gives me the screen position.

Is there a way to place an own View where the click is on the map?

peace

Answer (score -1):

You want to Create a Overly Class to know more please refer this click to know more detailed information about Google maps view and Overlay Items

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview

Comment: He's taking about Map api v2